# Sitecore ECM: Can't access Email Campaign Manager

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, ecm

I installed Sitecore ECM by using the installation guide (https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/ECM/ECM%202,-d-,2/Installation.aspx).

This is what I did:

1. install SPEAK1.O
2. update ConnectionString
3. install ECM2.2
4. Run Sitecore.EmailCampaing.sql against Reporting DB
5. Published Site

After completing these steps, I can see installed rendering items, templates, modules in System, and sample items in Content. However, I can't find any listed "E-mail Campaign" link for Email Campaign Manager in Sitecore start button.

We disabled Analytics feature temporary now, but I don't think it affects this issue. We are using Sitecore 8.0

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECM 2.2 is not compatible with Sitecore 8.0.

Use ExM 3.0 or ExM 3.1 and always follow [compatibility table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788).

And one more remark: ExM starting from 3.0 depends on List Manager which depends on contacts which depend on Analytics.

Comment: Is it okay to install 3.0 or 3.1 on the installed ECM2.2?

Updated: I found this page: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email_Experience_Manager/Email_Experience_Manager_30/Email_Experience_Manager_30_Initial_release.aspx

Comment: In general it is ok, if  it is you dev instance and you are ok to have trash items and files that you don't use.  But you have installed old version of SPEAK, which I guess could cause problems with Sitecore 8.0 itself, not only ExM. Better, start from scratch to exclude possible errors and save time.

Comment: I upgraded to EXM3.0 and I can see the link "Email Campaign Manager" in Sitecore start menu. Once I click, it goes to 404 page in `https://oursite/speak/emailcampaign`. I navigated the file system to find the path "/Website/Speak/", the "speak" folder doesn't exist. Do you know why??